# How to use svg clipPath?

Tags: svg, elm

After reading the doc, I tried this code:

```
main =
    svg [ width "100", height "100" ]
        [ Svg.clipPath [ id "clipCircle" ] [ circle [ cx "50", cy "50", r "50" ] [] ]
        , rect
            [ width "100"
            , height "100"
            , fill "red"
            , Svg.Attributes.clipPath "clipCircle"
            ]
            []
        ]
```

The rectangle is not clipped. A red square is still displayed instead of a circle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `url(...)` notation when referencing `clipCircle`:

```
Svg.Attributes.clipPath "url(#clipCircle)"
```